# IceCast radio data is not refreshing with Livewire/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, refresh, updating

I'm new to the world of Laravel and Livewire, and currently working on my homepage. I'm trying to incorporate a radio feature on my homepage and update the radio data. Unfortunately, the update functionality doesn't seem to be working at all. I'm wondering what could be the issue and if you have any ideas.

In my console I can see a POST with status code 200 /livewire/message/ice-cast

This is my code so far:

component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class IceCast extends Component
{
    public $currentStatus;
    public $currentSong;
    public $currentBitrate;
    public $currentListeners;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->getCurrentInfo();
    }

    public function getCurrentInfo()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->get("https://" . config('icecast.host') . ":" . config('icecast.adminport') . "/status-json.xsl");
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        if (isset($data['icestats']['source'])) {
            $this->currentStatus = $data['icestats']['source'];
        }

        if (isset($data['icestats']['source']['title'])) {
            $this->currentSong = $data['icestats']['source']['title'];
        }

        if (isset($data['icestats']['source']['bitrate'])) {
            $this->currentBitrate = $data['icestats']['source']['bitrate'];
        }

        if (isset($data['icestats']['source']['listeners'])) {
            $this->currentListeners = $data['icestats']['source']['listeners'];
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.icecast');
    }
}
?>
```

And my view:

```
@if(config('icecast.enabled'))
<div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="panel panel-chat shoutbox">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>
                    <i class="{{ config('other.font-awesome') }} fa-radio"></i> {{ __('blocks.icecast-title') }}
                    @if(isset($currentStatus))
                    <div style="float: right;">
                        <i class="{{ config('other.font-awesome') }} fa-head-side-headphones"></i> 
                        Zuhörer <span class="label label-default">{{ $currentListeners }}</span>
                    </div>
                    @endif              
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    @if(isset($currentStatus))
        
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <i class="{{ config('other.font-awesome') }} fa-user-music"></i>  Steamer
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <i class="{{ config('other.font-awesome') }} fa-album-collection"></i>  Titel
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ $currentSong }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <i class="{{ config('other.font-awesome') }} fa-waveform-path"></i>  Bitrate
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ $currentBitrate }}kbps
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <i class="{{ config('other.font-awesome') }} fa-users"></i>  Zuhörer
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    @else 
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <h4>Radio offline</h4>
                        </div>
                    @endif  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

dd($data); is showing this:

```
array:1 [▼ // app/Http/Livewire/IceCast.php:25
  "icestats" => array:7 [▼
    "admin" => "icemaster@localhost"
    "host" => "example.com"
    "location" => "Earth"
    "server_id" => "Icecast 2.4.4"
    "server_start" => "Mon, 01 May 2023 03:21:07 +0200"
    "server_start_iso8601" => "2023-05-01T03:21:07+0200"
    "source" => array:13 [▼
      "bitrate" => 320
      "genre" => "various"
      "listener_peak" => 1
      "listeners" => 0
      "listenurl" => "http://example.com:PORT/MOUNT"
      "server_description" => "VirtualDJ Broadcast"
      "server_name" => "test"
      "server_type" => "audio/mpeg"
      "server_url" => "https://www.virtualdj.com/"
      "stream_start" => "Tue, 16 May 2023 01:04:14 +0200"
      "stream_start_iso8601" => "2023-05-16T01:04:14+0200"
      "title" => "Zico SA & Zelda - Moments Like These"
      "dummy" => null
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: can you `dd($data);` after the line `$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);` and share the output.